# Vba turns cell in to date on mistake

Tags: vba

Hi how can I get around vba is converting a cell automatic to a data format when I add a value like 10 - 12 I just want the value in the cell to be 10 - 12 not a date

the code I use is "cFli is the value 10 - 12":

```
tsheet.Range("E2").Value = cFli
```

Comment: `tsheet.Range("E2").Value = "'" & cFli`

Comment: Nice thank you YowE3K

Comment: I can't close it as an answer if you don't make it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prepend a single-quotation mark to the value of a cell, which indicates to Excel to treat the rest of the string as text:

```
tsheet.Range("E2").Value = "'" & cFli
```

Note:  The `'` does not become part of the cell contents, although it will appear when editing the cell in future.

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by formatting the cell using the `Text` format:

```
tsheet.Range("E2").NumberFormat = "@"
tsheet.Range("E2").Value = cFli
```

Note: The formatting must be done **before** putting the value into the cell.

Comment: Thanks again YowE3K